# Pass wildcard to alias

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I use a modifies list command as alias (in KSH):

`alias ltf='ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/*'`

So the command `ltf` displays something like this:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Apr 18 12:00 /usr/test.txt`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Apr 18 12:00 /usr/test.log`

Now I want to use wildcards. But using `ltf *.log` does not work.

What is the best way to achieve that?

---

Update: I want to specify my question because the answers does not solve my problem so far: the command `ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/*` executes a list command with some options AND it displays the full path, which is an important point for me.

Unfortunately the *alias* approach does not allow wildcard parameters. My goal is to make this possible. Probably it is the best way to create the command as a function. This is mentioned in the answers, but it does not work yet (see comments).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Use a shell function instead of an alias:

```
function ltf {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    ls -lrtd1 ${PWD}/*
  else
    ls -lrtd1 $1
  fi
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, is there a similar notation in ksh like this one for bash: `[[ -z "$1" ]] && ls -lrtd1 "$PWD/*" || ls -lrtd1 "$1"`

Comment: I think it should be `ls -lrtd1 ${PWD}/$1` after the _else_ statement. Thanks!

Comment: @TechnoCore: no. `[ -z "$1" ]` is true if `"$1"` is the empty string, i.e. there is no argument.

Comment: the PWD command should also be executed if there **is** an argument; `ls -lrtd1 $1` does not show the full path

Comment: After some testing I think that this approach does not solve the problem. If the wildcard (eg. *.log) returns more then one file, only one file is listed by `ltf *.log`.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the wildcards are getting expanded by the shell in your current directory, not in $PWD. You can solve this by using a shell function rather than an alias and doing some quoting (I use $HOME in the example for my convenience) - put this in .bashrc:

```
ltf() {
    ls $HOME/$*
}
```

and then:

```
$ ltf '*.log'
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
alias ltf='ls -lrt -d -1 $1'
```

or if you want many params

```
alias ltf='ls -lrt -d -1 $@'
```

Comment: This doesn't work, `$1` etc aren't recognized by aliases. The reason you might get results anyway is `$1` will be an empty string, so `ltf path` will be `ls -lrt -d -1  path`. So you should use `alias ltf='ls -lrt -d -1'` for the same effect, and if that doesn't work, you will need to use a function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, wildcard expansion is done *before* calling shell functions, but not so with an alias.

If you don't need to change the input (which the OP does), this would work fine:

```
alias ltf='ls -lrt -d -1'
```

To achieve what the OP wants, within a shell function you would need to use the `$@` operator to access the set of files resulting from the wildcard expansion, which you would then need to prepend:

```
ltf() 
{ 
    #Prepend $PWD to the start of every input
    set -- "${@/#/$PWD/}"   

    #Run the command on the prepended input
    ls -lrt -d -1 $@;
}
```