# shell script with xargs and command line argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, xargs

I've a script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n /tmp/ /other_dir/ | xargs -n 1 -d\  -I % $1
```

What I would like to achieve is the possibility of using the delimiter "%" in the command associated to the $1 variable.
For example

```
. myscript "ls -la %*.txt"
```

which should list only .txt files in each directory.
I've tried also without the quotes but it doesn't work.
The message I get now is that /tmp/*.txt and /other_dir/*.txt are not existent.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087407/xargs-respect-wildcards-in-searches

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a wildcard parameter to a bash file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19458104/608639), [pass wildcard to command in shell script and store it in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48339963/608639), [How to access literal wildcard argument before it's expanded to matching files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060389/608639), [Pass wildcard to alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5699749/608639), etc.

Comment: This question is really unclear; if the proposed duplicates don't help you, maybe try to rephrase your question to explain in more detail what you hope would happen.